# Federation Utility throws an error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: .net, wif, federated-identity

I am trying to use the "Create STS project in the current solution" option in the Federation Utility of Windows Identity Foundation 4.0 (64 bit) from Visual Studio 2010 with Administrator account. I have IIS 7.5 on Windows Home Premium.

After I click on the Finish button, I get the error "The system cannot find the file specified." message.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the problem is without knowing which file is missing.

I believe you can invoke fedutil.exe from the command line, and that there are command line parameters to get it to log more error details. Fedutil.exe is under %ProgramFiles%\Windows Identity Foundation SDK.

If not, you could also try debugging this with Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Configure the filter to watch fedutil.exe, and check for any file system misses and you should be able to find which file its complaining about.

Comment: Just to note that FedUtil has a comment that this option is only available via VS. But +1 for ProcessMonitor.